# Result of Dense layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
print(model.layers[312].output)
```

outputs (None,2048)

layer 312 code

```
Dense(2048, activation='relu',name='first_dense')
```

number of samples is 8732. I need the output of first_dense layer in shape of (8732,2048). In other words, I need the result of this layer in all samples. How can do it??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a sub-model and make predictions

```
new_model = Model(model.input, model.layers[312].output)
new_model.predict(...)
```